# GCd of a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Calculate $gcd\left(\frac{2^{40}+1}{2^8+1}, 2^8+1 \right)=k$.

Generalization I saw in a book: let $ q=\Pi_{i=1}^{n}p_{i} $
obviously, $ 2^{r}+1|2^{q}+1 $,$ r|q $
here we have $ 2^n $ divisors,and we also have $ \frac{2^{q}+1}{2^{r}+1} $
so,we have $ 4^{n} $ divisors now
we only say why do not exist same divisors
it equals to say that exists x,y such that $ (2^{x}+1)(2^{y}+1)=2^{q}+1 $
it is same as $ 2^{x+y}+2^{x}+2^{y}=2^{q} $
compare the power of 2 then we have $ x=y=1,q=3 $ ( $ \rightarrow\leftarrow $ )

I don't know if this generalization serves this question. If it fits, how do I apply it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z=2^8$.  We also have $2^{40}+1 = z^5+1 = (z+1)(z^4-z^3+z^2-z+1)$.  So we're really trying to find $\text{gcd}\left( z^4-z^3+z^2-z+1, z+1 \right)$.

From here, I checked the primality of $2^8+1$, and it is prime.  In fact, it is one of a very few Fermat primes.  So we need to prove that $2^8 + 1$ is prime.  Possibly it's easiest to do this by trial division of the primes $p \le \sqrt{257}$.

Then, just divide $z^4-z^3+z^2-z+1 = 2^{32}-2^{24}+2^{16}-2^8+1 = 4278255361$ by $257$.  You'll find that there is a remainder.  So the GCD is $1$!

---

Alternatively, if you didn't want to check the primality of $2^8+1$, you could divide $z^4-z^3+z^2-z+1$ by $z+1$ to get $5$.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find how your generalization fits into this problem, but I'll give it some more thought.

Comment: Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $z +1.$ Then $z\equiv$ $ -1\pmod p$ so $z^4-z^3+z^2-z+1\equiv$ $ \equiv (-1)^4-(-1)^3+(-1)^2-(-1)+1\equiv$ $ 5 \pmod p$, so $p$ does not divide $ z^4-z^3+z^2-z+1$ when $p\ne 5.$ But also $5$ is not a prime divisor of $z+1$ when $z=2^8$. By Fermat's Little Theorem a prime divisor $p$ of  $1+2^{2^n}$ must satisfy $p\equiv 1\pmod {2^{n+1}}.$

Comment: About checking primarlity: if $p|2^8+1$ then $2\in\mathbb F_p^\times$ has order $16$, so $p\equiv1\pmod{16}$. However, there are no such primes $\le\sqrt{257}$. Thus $2^8+1$ must be prime.